# Correct formula for back transforming from power model when including dummies in excel?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, forecasting, logarithm

Suppose I had the following data set

```
VOL TRGT NPI    Q1  Q2  Q3  COMP NPI
7428    1.49    1   0   0   8.31
6873    1.49    1   0   0   8.93
7041    1.43    1   0   0   8.94
6519    1.49    1   0   0   8.94
6028    1.49    1   0   0   8.93
6102    1.49    1   0   0   7.93
7249    1.49    1   0   0   7.93
6817    1.49    1   0   0   7.95
5621    1.49    0   1   0   6.94
5127    1.49    0   1   0   6.94
5183    1.44    0   1   0   6.94
4625    1.49    0   1   0   6.91
4915    1.5 0   1   0   6.9
4457    1.49    0   1   0   6.95
4324    1.49    0   1   0   6.95
3762    1.49    0   1   0   6.96
3477    1.48    0   0   1   7.74
3812    1.48    0   0   1   5.89
4719    1.46    0   0   1   6.68
5563    1.25    0   0   1   6.78
3828    1.47    0   0   1   7.55
3807    1.47    0   0   1   5.5
3465    1.46    0   0   1   7.68
3161    1.45    0   0   1   7.51
```

Then I transform my X's and Y's in excel using LN function in order to use the log-log model.

```
    VOL TRGT NPI    Q1  Q2  Q3  COMP NPI
8.913   0.399   1   0   0   2.117
8.835   0.399   1   0   0   2.189
8.860   0.358   1   0   0   2.191
8.782   0.399   1   0   0   2.191
8.704   0.399   1   0   0   2.189
8.716   0.399   1   0   0   2.071
8.889   0.399   1   0   0   2.071
8.827   0.399   1   0   0   2.073
8.634   0.399   0   1   0   1.937
8.542   0.399   0   1   0   1.937
8.553   0.365   0   1   0   1.937
8.439   0.399   0   1   0   1.933
8.500   0.405   0   1   0   1.932
8.402   0.399   0   1   0   1.939
8.372   0.399   0   1   0   1.939
8.233   0.399   0   1   0   1.940
8.154   0.392   0   0   1   2.046
8.246   0.392   0   0   1   1.773
8.459   0.378   0   0   1   1.899
8.624   0.223   0   0   1   1.914
8.250   0.385   0   0   1   2.022
8.245   0.385   0   0   1   1.705
8.150   0.378   0   0   1   2.039
8.059   0.372   0   0   1   2.016
```

Which will return the following coefficients after regression

```
    Coefficients
Intercept   10.66318595
TRGT NPI    -2.402481749
Q1  0
Q2  -0.436542517
Q3  -0.703941673
COMP NPI    -0.422021765
```

Suppose now I want to predict the VOL using a TRGT value of 1.99 and a COMP NPI of 7.99 during Q1.

QUESTION:
WHAT WOULD THE CORRECT FORMULA BE?
Is it?

```
=EXP(Intercept   + TRGT NPI * LN(1.99) + COMP NPI * LN(7.99) + Q1 * 1 + Q2 * 0 + Q3 * 0 )
```

with values

```
=EXP(10.6 + -2.40 * LN(1.99) + -0.42 * LN(7.99) + 0 * 1 + -0.43 * 0 + -0.70 * 0)
```

Comment: It depends on what thing you want a correct formula for. If your model on the logs provides a correct model for the mean on the log scale and you want "the correct formula" for the mean on the original untransformed scale, then simply exponentiating is not correct. On the other hand, if you wanted "the correct formula" for the median on the original scale, just exponentiating might in some circumstances be perfectly sensible.

Comment: The formula should be the correct one for predicting (VOL) volume at the (TRGT) price (as described above). Can you elaborate a little more? Be mindful that the regression is in excel. So I am transforming then back transforming.

Comment: predicting *what*  aspect of the distribution of volume? "Correct" in what sense?  You're not defining what you want at all. I'm not sure what's unclear about my previous comment so I am not sure what to elaborate. Can you ask a more specific question about what is unclear?

Comment: I've stated my specific goals. I have stated my specific data set I am working with. I have explained the transformation I am using. I have no idea how to be more specific. I have not hidden or concealed a single bit of information. I want to predict VOL using the data above....How is this not clear?

Comment: Here is the goal in straight forward terms: How many units will I sell (VOL) during Q1 at the price of 1.99 (TRGT NPI)  while a  competitive item is priced at ($7.99) (COMP NPI) ???

Comment: "The number of units you will sell" is a *random variable*, NOT a fixed value. We can, under certain assumptions, calculate a *distribution* over future values, for example, but nobody can (reasonably) state "you *WILL* sell 17 units". Your stated goal makes no sense. Please re-read what I wrote earlier keeping in mind that you *CANNOT* reliably predict (as a point estimate) the *actual* number sold. You could estimate/forecast the mean, or the median or any number of other things about the distribution (a point which I have raised repeatedly).

Comment: Alternatively, you could ask for an interval estimate (such as a prediction interval for the actual number sold). Or you could state a loss function for a point estimate, and that would correspond to a particular estimator.

Comment: Hi Glen, I feel we are slipping into a discussion more about semantics than math. I think your point is a good one and I agree. It goes without saying that nobody has a crystal ball and any estimate foretasted would be just a guess based on analysis. Semantics aside,  I believe the formula I placed above is the one I would use in this case to make my guess. If you disagree for any reason I would love to hear why. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My objection is based *entirely* in the mathematics; even though the explanation was verbal. It's the distinction between distributions and point-summaries of distributions, like means. If you want a point forecast, you need to specify how exactly to summarize the distribution of future values under the model. You're asking for *future values* but you don't get future values; statistical models (sometimes explicitly, sometimes implicitly) are about distributions. So you need to say how you want to summarize that distribution. For example, many people ask for the expected future values ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... As an example, imagine I roll two six-sided dice and take the smaller of the two numbers that come up. If someone asks me to predict the next outcome of that, there are six possible results $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ with probabilities $(\frac{6}{21},\frac{5}{21},\frac{4}{21},\frac{3}{21},\frac{2}{21},\frac{1}{21})$. The most common outcome is $1$ (the mode), the median outcome is $2$ and the mean outcome is $8/3$. What's your prediction in that case, the mode, the median, the mean, or something else?

Comment: So why ever use regression analysis if we can't make some conjecture using our observed data? I work for a company that wants answers. Some long winded dialog about all the ways we could interpret our data is not helpful to my employer. With regard to my formula as long as it is A valid (of many) ways to interpret our data I will use it.

Comment: I don't doubt that you are a math genius Glen, but so far none of this is helpful. Allow me to try again to ask you Glen, I feel like if I ask the right question I will get something helpful. Suppose YOU have the data above and a guy paying you for answers wants you to predict how many units will sell in Q1  at the price of $1.99. You know that if you give him all the talk about not know distribution blah blah that you get fired. What answer do you give him and how did you calculate it?

Comment: Why don't you just explain what I need to do instead of running me in circles? You clearly understand something I don't so help me to understand. I would be grateful. I need an answer so far all I have is theory

Comment: I've been *trying* to help you understand. You're saying "jump" ("predict") and I'm asking "how high?" ("what kind of prediction?"). You're saying "I need some nails" and I'm saying "sure, what kind? you want brads? roofing nails?". If you look at the dice example I gave can you see that different answers are possible? If I asked you to predict the next outcome (for the smaller value on two dice), what would your prediction be? Answering your original question requires picking an answer like one of the possible answers there, which then determines the formula.

Comment: I want E where E is expected value. IF that means on average then okay, whatever word is the one that gets me an answer I am all ears. (mean outcome) or mean mode and median. anything and all 3 would be amazing.

Comment: What is the formula I provided doing? Giving the mean?

Comment: No, it's below the mean. Under certain assumptions you might get a median that way. I've discussed it more in an answer. There are other posts on site which discuss the issue with transformation and means.

Comment: When you exponentiate, you should probably include your coefficients to more than two or three significant figures (five might be better); it can make a fairly substantial difference in the exponentiated answers. Once you have the answer it makes sense to round it off to about three figures though; you just want more precision in the intermediate calculations.

Answer (score 1):

If you take logs then do regression on the log scale that will fit a mean on the log-scale.

If you then exponentiate the log-scale prediction you *won't* get a mean prediction on the original variable. In fact if you want the mean the prediction will be too low on average.

That may be fine, though. If the error distribution on the log scale is close to symmetric (which you can assess approximately by looking at the residuals) you'd essentially also have a median prediction on the log-scale; and if you exponentiate in that case you'd still have a median for the original-scale variable. [if mean = median on the log scale then mean > median on the original scale, as long as there's any variability at all]

If your residuals look more-or-less symmetric and you're happy being under half the time and over half the time in your prediction (which is reasonable in some acses), then sure, just exponentiate.

If you want to get the average right there's a number of issues to deal with, one way to do it approximately (assuming your $n$ is so large you're prepared to ignore uncertainty in the variance estimate -- it's something of a fudge) would be to scale up your predictions by $\exp(s^2)$ (though that would still be too low for several reasons), where $s$ is the residual standard deviation.

However, prediction intervals for the next observation can just be exponentiated.

[Personally, if I was really trying to get a mean prediction, I'd consider a gamma GLM with log-link which would have a pretty similar sort of fit on the log-scale - since if it's a reasonable model the transformation issue is avoided. If your residuals from the regression are a bit left skew that would probably be an excellent choice]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated. Do you have a formula for using the supplied data above and getting an answer? (Such as GLM with log-link) Also am I to understand that there is nothing wrong per se with the formula I provided above?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with exponentiating back and using it as your prediction, if it does what you need  -- if you don't need a prediction that's right on average (it is still right or close to right in other ways), everything should be fine. I can't give a formula for fitting the GLM with log-link since it requires an iterative solution (it should be possible to fit one in Excel using tools like Solver but it would be a lot of work). but given a fitted GLM, predictions work just like you have in your answer. I'll show this on your data.

Comment: Unfortunately I managed to lose the entire edit with the information for the Gamma GLM. I'll have to redo it later.

Comment: Okay, I will look forward to it. Thank you for all of your help Glen. I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.